# usecols to be case insensitive in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to cycle through large number of CSVs with same column names, however some of them have a different case.

I am using "usecols" in my code which throws an error when the case does not match mycols list.

```
df=pd.read_csv(fname,sep=",", encoding="ISO-8859-1",quotechar='"',error_bad_lines=False,dtype=object,usecols=mycols,index_cols=False)
```

How do I make sure that usecols ignores the case?

Thanks

Comment: use a lambda `usecols = lambda x : x.lower() in mycols`

Comment: Doesn't work because some columns being read are in upper case and some are lowercase

Comment: well you could lower-case the list?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=",", encoding="ISO-8859-1",  quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False,dtype=object, usecols= lambda x : x.lower() in mycols,index_col=False)

Comment: Above code is not reading any lines from the CSV

Comment: @Datanovice- all working now. Thank you

Comment: no problem here to help :) happy coding

Comment: Spoke too early, realised the resulting DF is now missing data for columns where case did not match, any ideas why?

Comment: maybe white space on columns add `lambda x  : x.lower().strip()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `pandas` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) (describing the `callable` version of `usecols`)

> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the
>   column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
>   True. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']. Using this parameter results in
>   much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

Comment: @failsafe100 The code is in the answer, just replace the list with with yours.

Comment: Silly me, my list was in proper case...it works. Thank you

Comment: `usecols` just allows you to decide whether a column will be used or not. It doesn't normalize the column names. 

To normalize column names, you can subsequently grab the columns using `df.columns` and then apply functions to them as you would any other index.