# Pandas read_csv() - Case insensitive column names for converters/dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `pd.read_csv()` to load file that might have column names of unknown case. Using lambda for `usecols` argument as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62412830/2059689), I can choose which columns to load regardless the case, and with method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726029/how-can-i-make-pandas-dataframe-column-headers-all-lowercase) I can access these columns like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, usecols=lambda x: x.lower() in ['foo', 'bar'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

print(df['foo'])  # Works no matter which column name case is in the file
```

But is there a way to use the `dtypes`/`converters` parameters in this case?

I had two workaround ideas in mind:

1. Load all the data as strings and do the conversions in my code later. This seems way less performant.
2. Open the file just to read the header, analyze it, then open again with prior knowledge of the actual case of the column names (wrap it all as a function).

Are there other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

You can read in just the first line of data to grab the columns. I'd recommend doing this via the built-in `csv` module, or even with `pandas` since they'll both have easy handling of quoting.

Using `pandas` you can do something like this:

```py
from io import StringIO
from pandas import read_csv

data = StringIO('''
a,B,c,D
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,7
'''.strip())

# expected lower-case column names mapped to dtypes
# intentionally left out column 'D'
dtypes = {'a': 'Int64', 'b': 'int32', 'c': 'float64'}

# `nrows=0` will only read in the column names and an empty DataFrame
columns = read_csv(data, nrows=0).columns

# only need to do this since `data` acts as an open file-handle
data.seek(0)

# create mapping of actual column names → dtype based on a matching `.casefold()`
#  if you're unfamiliar with `string.casefold()` you can think of it like `string.lower()`
new_dtypes = {
    col: dtypes[col.casefold()]
    for col in columns if col.casefold() in dtypes
}
df = read_csv(data, usecols=new_dtypes.keys(), dtype=new_dtypes)

print(df)
   a  B    c
0  1  2  3.0
1  5  6  7.0
```

Comment: So basically, you say my 2nd workaround is the best approach. Thanks!